# Using TikTok's iOS Login kit with Flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, tiktok

I'm experimenting with adding TikTok authentication to my Flutter app (iOS only for now).
My first intention was to utilize [TikTok's Login Kit](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-ios-login-kit-with-swift) for this and I started to look at how to [call native iOS code from Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-swift-tab).

I have managed to set up the necessary piping in order to call the iOS code from Flutter but it's when I want to respond with a result I'm having issues.

The TikTok auth flow is initiated fine, I get taken to my TikTok App on my phone where I can authenticate or cancel and finally get redirected back to my app. As a result of this, I'm expecting the `completion` closure to be called, where I can report back the response to Flutter. **This does not seem to happen.**

Here's my AppDelegate.swift

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.flutter.tiktok", binaryMessenger: controller as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)
        
        channel.setMethodCallHandler { (methodCall : FlutterMethodCall, result : @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            if methodCall.method == "OpenTiktok"
            {
                let scopes = ["user.info.basic"]
                let scopesSet = NSOrderedSet(array:scopes)
                let request = TikTokOpenSDKAuthRequest()
                request.permissions = scopesSet
                request.state = "1234567890"
                
                request.send(controller, completion: { (resp : TikTokOpenSDKAuthResponse) -> Void in
                    result(resp.code ?? "NO_CODE") // <-- THIS DOES NOT HAPPEN
                })
            }
        }
        
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    override func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        guard let sourceApplication = options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
              let annotation = options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation] else {
                  return false
              }
        
        if TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        if TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleOpen url: URL) -> Bool {
        if TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: nil, annotation: "") {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm triggering the message from Flutter:

```dart
Future<void> openTiktok() async {
  try {
    var code = await platform.invokeMethod("OpenTiktok");
    setState(() {
      _code = code;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Appreciate any kind of feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Got things to work finally and it had nothing to do with Flutter at all and was purely an iOS thing. Got some inspiration from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379573/tiktok-loginkit-ios-integration-issue).

What I had to do was to tweak the second `application` override.
The `options` dictionary seems to always be empty which caused the `false` return.

This is the final version of that application override:

```
override func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    if TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: nil, annotation: "") {
        return true
    }
    return super.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Thanks